# ethereum ganache is failing with "Exceeds block gas limit" even though I have enough balance

Tags: ethereum, ganache

I am testing an ethereum smart contract with ganache and web3.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

web3.eth.getBalance(contractOwner).then(console.log); // this returns 99953972490000000000

const sendTxOptions = {from: contractOwner, gas: 1000*1000*10}
contract.methods.my_method().send(sendTxOptions).then(console.log);

(node:80755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: Exceeds block gas limit
```

`1000*1000*10` is less than `99953972490000000000`. Why is this failing?

Note: I've already searched for other similar questions, such as this one, but they do not answer my question.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26577/error-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-out-of-gas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *ETH* balance (not *gas*):

```
web3.eth.getBalance(contractOwner).then(console.log); // this returns 99953972490000000000
```

Use `estimateGas` instead: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas

`my_method()` consumes more *gas* than `block gas limit`. You can increase the gas limit for the block for Ganache, but it is better to optimize the function, otherwise in real network there may still be problems.

Comment: `npx ganache-cli -l 10000000`

Comment: thx. the idea was to compute how much it costs to store data in the blockchain.

Comment: the `estimateGas` call throws also the "Exceeds block gas limit" error if there is not enough gas. that's funny, haha.